# How to post json to REST from ADF

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-logic-apps

I am building a pipeline in Azure Data Factory.  In this pipeline, we are retrieving data from a API in json format and transform into another JSON format and want to post to other API.  As per my understanding ADF Data Copy activity doesn't support REST API as output/sink service.

Just wondering what are the other ways to implement this pipeline without much coding.

Comment: Did you got your Solution?

Answer (score 1):

If the transformations are fairly straightforward then your pipeline may be as simple as:

1. Web Activity with method=GET
2. Web Activity with method=POST with body set to an expression which transforms the output of the first Web Activity in some way.

You get the output of an activity with this expression:

```
activity('ActivityNameHere').output
```

Comment: Should be there a transform activity between Get Web Activity and Post Activity as response from post cannot be passed to post as it is.

Comment: @Nps depends on the transformations you are making. I’d you are just taking a portion of the output from the first activity then that’s a simple expression like `activity('FirstWebActivityName').output.subsection1` as the body of the second web activity.

Answer (score 0):

You could also save the output json to a cache sink and try passing that to another data flow source